# No change in font face in html to pdf generation using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext, font-face, html-to-pdf

I'm using a HTML Rich-Text Editor to help me create a template for dynamic PDF reports, and it's working fine except that it doesn't change the font-face.

This editor is using the font tag instead of CSS styles, and I would welcome any way to programmatically change the font tags to equivalent tags using styles instead.

HTML (yes its messy, its from a WYSIWYG editor):

```
<div>&nbsp;
<br>
  <div align="center">
    <font size="5">
      <b>
        <br>
          <div align="center">
            <font font-face="Times New Roman" size="5">
              <b>Example 
              <font size="6">Chamber 
              <font size="5">
                <font size="4">Website</font>
              </font></font>Quotes</b>
            </font>
            <font face="Times New Roman">
              <br>
                <font face="Times New Roman">
                  <br>~
                  <font face="Times New Roman" color="#0000FF">
                    <b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <u>&nbsp;[!PlanName]&nbsp;</u></b>
                  </font>
                  <font face="Times New Roman">
                    <br>~
                    <font face="Times New Roman" color="#0000FF">
                      <b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>
                    </font>
                    <font face="Times New Roman" color="#0000FF">
                      <b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                      <font color="#000000">Deductible&nbsp;
                      $[!PlanDeductible]:&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></b>
                    </font>
                    <font face="Times New Roman" color="#B0B0FF">
                    [!PlanRate]
                    <br>
                      <font face="Times New Roman">/~/~</font>
                      <br>
                        <br>
                          <br>
                            <font face="Courier New" size="1">
                            Copyright Example.com</font>
                            <br>
                              <br>
                                <font face="Arial">test</font>
                                <br></br>
                              </br>
                            </br>
                          </br>
                        </br>
                      </br>
                    </br></font></br>
                  </font></br>
                </font>
              </br>
            </font>
          </div>
        </br>
      </b>
    </font>
  </div>
</br></div>
```

C#:

```
public static byte[] ConvertHtmlToPdf(string html)
{
    html = HtmlPostProcessor.Process(html);
    byte[] fileData = null;
    string tempPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TempDirectory"];
    string tempPDFFile = Path.Combine(tempPath, Guid.NewGuid() + ".pdf");
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 50, 50, 50, 50);

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(tempPDFFile, FileMode.Create))
    {
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
        using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(html))
        {
            List<IElement> parsedList = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(stringReader, null );
            document.Open();
            foreach (IElement item in parsedList)
            {
                document.Add(item);
            }
            document.Close();
        }
    }

    FileStream generatedPDF = File.Open(tempPDFFile, FileMode.Open);
    fileData = new byte[(int)generatedPDF.Length]; 
    int result = generatedPDF.Read(fileData, 0, (int)generatedPDF.Length);

    generatedPDF.Close();

    File.Delete(tempPDFFile);

    return fileData;
}
```

**EDIT**

I've been using iTextSharp version 5.1.1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest, brute-force way is to call [FontFactory.RegisterDirectories()](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/FontFactory.html#registerDirectories%28%29) *before* calling `HTMLWorker.ParseToList()`. Be warned, however - the method attempts to register/map **all** fonts on the running system.

So if you're running this in ASP.NET, for example, you probably want to put the call in global.asax.

**EDIT**: Working example using `FontFactory.RegisterDirectories()` and the HTML you provided above:

```
FontFactory.RegisterDirectories();
using (Document document = new Document()) {
  PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);
  document.Open();
  List<IElement> objects = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(
    new StringReader(html), null);
  foreach (IElement element in objects) {
    document.Add(element);
  }
}
```

Just substitute `Response.OutputStream` with the `Stream` of your choice. [Result PDF file from above](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=0B88fJJybQ9yPMmY3NTM1NjktNzNmYy00OTVhLTljN2ItMTU0MWEyYTBjNjU0&hl=en_US).

Comment: Is there a way of registering just a few fonts? Say 8 web fonts?

Comment: Also, inserting the line FontFactory.RegisterDirectories() right before HTMLWorker.ParseToList() didn't do a thing except make it slow, but I'll look over that documentation you linked to more tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: What version are you using? I tested with 5.1.3 using the HTML in your example and it worked. The [result PDF file is here](http://goo.gl/Tv242). You might want to insert the call to ` FontFactory.RegisterDirectories()` before you even open the `Document` object, sorry. And i'll try and see if I can come up with an example to register a limited amount of fonts later today/tomorrow.

Comment: I looked at that PDF and you can tell by the lack of serif on that E in example that the font is not working.

Comment: @capn - your HTML snippet above has the following font-faces: Times New Roman, Courier New, and Arial. If you open the linked PDF and look at the embedded fonts, they're all there. (there's no serif font-face in the HTML snippet) To answer your first question, you can register just a few fonts by calling one of the overloaded [FontFactory.RegisterDirectory](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/FontFactory.html) methods, but you **must** put the font files you want in the spcified directory.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Ghz2c.png Look at the 'E' in the screen print, and the E in the PDF you linked. The 'E' in the PDF you linked doesn't appear to be the same. Have your own browser render the code: http://pastehtml.com/view/bh33vypyz.html

Comment: Ok, the starting 'E' did not get recognized as Times New Roman, but changing around the HTML in the WYSIWYG tool got it there. FontFactory.RegisterDirectory(@"C:\Windows\Fonts") is still pretty slow, but it works, thanks!

Comment: That's good. Did you try copying the 8 or so fonts to a different directory, **then** calling `FontFactory.RegisterDirectory` with **that** directory? It should run much faster, since it's not scanning/mapping **all** the Windows system fonts. Sorry, I tested on a laptop with an SSD, so I wasn't affected by the slow loading time.

Answer (score 1):

HTMLWorker is obsolete. You need to switch to the new [XMLWorker](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/index.html) class.
But if you want to use the HTMLWorker, you can define a global style for it as well:

```
StyleSheet styles = new StyleSheet();
styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.FONTFAMILY, "tahoma");
//...
//and then
var parsedHtmlElements = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(data, styles);
```

Comment: I can't find XMLWorker anywhere in the iTextSharp library, I only see it referenced in the Java iText library. Is there a namespace I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

http://hivelocity.dl.sourceforge.net/project/itextsharp/itextsharp/iTextSharp-5.4.1/itextsharp-all-5.4.1.zip

there you can get the last version of iTextSharp(5.4.1) Library

http://hivelocity.dl.sourceforge.net/project/itextsharp/xmlworker/xmlworker-5.4.1/itextsharp.xmlworker-all-5.4.1.zip

and here is the XML worker... it only works with the same version of iTextSharp (5.4.1)