# Itextsharp rendering html as html source

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, itext

I am having following code in itextsharp

```
productCell.AddElement(new Phrase(Server.HtmlDecode((this.Product.Description != null) ? this.Product.Description : ""), "Arial"));
```

But the page is rendered as html source.
Does anybody have solution?
Rest of code is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. works for me

```
        FontFactory.RegisterDirectories();
        List<IElement> htmlarraylist = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader("<html><head></head><body><div style='font-family: Cambria'>" + text + "</div></body></html>"), null);
        for (int k = 0; k < htmlarraylist.Count; k++)
        {
            cell.AddElement((IElement)htmlarraylist[k]);
        }
       Tbl.AddCell(cell);
```

Comment: hi thanks for answer, this worked but how do i add font to element now?

Comment: add it in the html or trying providing the CSS as the second parameter for ParseToList

Comment: tried this "<div style='font-family:" + Arial+ "'>"+htmldata+"</div>" not working

Comment: Answer updated.Refer here for more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452286/no-change-in-font-face-in-html-to-pdf-generation-using-itextsharp

Comment: Works fine for me i have tested it.add the fonts as i added and not with +

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer font part, so that it help anyone, take para add in chunks and apply font to chunks

```
List<IElement> htmlarraylist = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(htmldata), null);
Paragraph pdesc=new Paragraph();
    for (int k = 0; k < htmlarraylist.Count; k++)
    {
        //Applies font to each chunk within para
        foreach (Chunk chunk in htmlarraylist[k].Chunks)
        {
            pdesc.Add(new Chunk(chunk.ToString(),arial));
        }
    }
    yourCellInDocument.AddElement(pdesc);
```